# Xamarin projects not inheriting from shared library correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection

I've started working with Xamarin Forms using the .NET Standard. When trying to use a dependency injection for platform specific code (in this case, different code for Android and iOS), the project can not find the interface from the base project.

I was following a guide with an example shown below
[image]

However Visual Studio does not find my interface from the base project in the Android / iOS projects.

[image]

The namespace can not be found either. The only one it finds is ProblemCode.Android. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: does the Android project have a reference to the Shared Project?

Comment: Yes, the reference manager says it has a reference to the base project (ProblemCode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to the your shared project in the last image.

However, i have noticed with *.NetStandard*, *Xamarin* gets confused sometimes, Though it can get confused at the best of times for no reason at all.

Usually when i have benign problem with *Xamarin* i try the following sets.

- Clean the solution

  - Clear the Bin and Obj directories of all projects.
  - Clean the solution
  - Restart visual studio
  - Rebuild the solution
- Sometimes i have needed to Remove/Add the references to the shared .NetStandard projects back to the Device Projects

  - Maybe make sure it builds independently without problems
- In some cases (probably not this one) it helps to Reinstall all nugets

---

***Note*** : I'm not sure this will help you in your case, but it was at least worth mentioning